# Подружить Java и Python

Tags: java, python, сервер

заранее извиняюсь за столь общий и размытый вопрос.
Собираемся писать приложение (некоммерческое) для платформы Android, хотим прикрутить к нему сервер, который будет принимать запросы от приложения и отправлять python команды устройствам.
Кто может посоветовать стек технологий, может кто работал над подобным? Как облегчить задачу по максимуму?

Comment: Сервер на питоне? Сокет-сервер или http?

Comment: а какой будет целесообразнее?

Comment: я бы обошелся и вовсе без сервера, так как смартфон и устройства будут внутри одной сети, но не знаю, как отправить python запрос изнутри java

Comment: Вот тут мне не понятно `python запрос изнутри java`. Что значит питон запрос? Я так понимаю, что это значит послать запрос к питону, а с учетом того, что вы писали про сервер и приложение на андроид, предположу, что это сервер питона, который, например по http, будет принимать запросы, обрабатывать и возвращать результат

Answer (score 3):

Можно через [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) сделать вебсервер, минимальный пример:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Чтобы в питон установить его:

```
pip install flask
```

---

Например, запускаю я сервер как локальный с портом 12345:

```
app.run('localhost', port=12345)
```

В консоли питона появится сообщение:

> - Running on http://localhost:12345/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Далее, пишу код на `java` для отправки GET HTTP запроса к тому серверу:

```
...

public static String getHTML(String urlToRead) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    try (BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String html = getHTML("http://localhost:12345/");
    System.out.println(html);
}
```

Результат:

> Hello World!

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте [RESTful](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST)-сервис на [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: спасибо, будем посмотреть